# How to simulate ctrl+c to implement copy in ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xorg, clipboard

I want to implement the simulation of copy signals in Ubuntu, as follows:

1. Register a shortcut key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.
2. When the user selects text content in any window and presses this shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, the program can simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and send a system copy signal to the system, and then the user-selected content will be written to the clipboard.

In short, my expected effect is that when the program (as shown below) is running, I select a piece of text in any window on the screen and press the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Its effect can be equivalent to the effect of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. The text segment I selected will be automatically writes to clipboard.

But judging from the running results now, it can register and recognize the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, but it does not achieve the real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> copy effect. My program looks like:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
    XEvent ev;

    // Register the shortcut
    unsigned int modifiers = ControlMask; // ctrl
    KeyCode keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XK_1); // 1
    if (XGrabKey(dpy, keycode, modifiers, root, True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync)) {
        qDebug() << "Hotkey registered!" << endl;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Failed to register hotkey." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (true) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        if (ev.type == KeyPress && ev.xkey.keycode == keycode) {
            qDebug() << "Hotkey pressed!";

            // Simulate ctrl+c to copy
            Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
            if(display == nullptr)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            KeyCode ctrlKey = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Control_L);
            KeyCode cKey = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_C);
            XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, ctrlKey, True, 0);
            XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, cKey, True, 0);
            XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, cKey, False, 0);
            XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, ctrlKey, False, 0);
            qDebug() << "send ctrl+c";
            XFlush(display);
            XCloseDisplay(display);
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice?

(Why not use ctrl+c directly? Because there is a subsequent processing process~~)

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what you want to achieve? It would seem to me that just hitting Ctrl+C will already achieve what you want. Or is your question related to remapping Ctrl+C to another keyboard combination? Text selected in Linux is on the primary clipboard already. That could be written to the regular clipboard. You need to better identify what you actually want to achieve. As written now, I would say: "just use Ctrl+C instead"

Comment: I refined my question and posted the corresponding code. Because there is a subsequent processing process, so I can not use ctrl+c instead. Any more suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: In short, you want your shortcut key to do something that also involves copying highlighted text. Your current approach will work on Xorg only. If you currently run Wayland, then that is already why it does not work. If you test in Xorg, you may need a pause before the faked Ctrl+C: As you still hold Ctrl (from hitting Ctrl+1), the system only sees 'c' when you simulate Ctrl+c. Consider using the Linux primary clipboard: the highlighted text is there, ready to be retrieved in the program, on Xorg *and* Wayland.

Comment: I need to implement the above functionality in x11. I tried pausing for a second before issuing ctrl+c, but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'll keep trying and reading directly from the clipboard will be my final alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input-remapper:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt install input-remapper

Go to applications, search for 'input remapper'.

Choose your keyboard from the device list, create or just use the current
‘Preset’.

Click 'new entry' then press ctrl+1 on the keyboard. Afterwards, input your map key ( ctrl+shift+c in this case ).

Finally, click on 'apply'.

You're ready to use ctrl+1 to emulate ctrl+c on X11 and terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to achieve this through code. I refined my question and posted the corresponding code. If you have more suggestions, please tell me, thanks!